# Only allow numbers in an EditText

Tags: android

How do I allow only numbers in an `EditText`. I don't want to allow decimals or letters, but only numeric values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `inputType="number"` in `EditText`.

Answer (score 3):

`android:inputType="number"` in your edittext in xml file.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the above comments, this will also work(However, it does not make the keyboard switch to number mode) :

```
android:digits="0123456789"
```

Answer (score 1):

JAVA : `edittext.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);`

in XML:

```
<EditText   
    // ...
    android:inputType="number" 
    // ...  />
```

Comment: Thats not how you comment in XMLs... its <!-- text -->

Comment: Firstly you are wrong, comments inside a tag are not allowed in [XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml-20060816/#sec-comments). Secondly, it's just a way to tell him to add what he wants ! :p